# Uninitialize warning in OpenMP

Tags: c, initialization, openmp

I have a code snippet which uses OpenMP to parallel the "for loop" :

```
float **filterpart=NULL, **model_tmp, **model;

/* Omit the memory allocation, and initialize the element to 0.0 here */

#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) \
private(i,j,ii,jj,filterpart) \
shared(NYG,NXG,hfs,model_tmp,model,filt_grid)
#endif
    for (j=1;j<=NYG;j++){ 
        for (i=1;i<=NXG;i++){ 
                for (ii=-hfs;ii<=hfs;ii++){
                    for (jj=-hfs;jj<=hfs;jj++){
                        filterpart[ii+hfs+1][jj+hfs+1] = model_tmp[j+jj][i+ii];
                    }
                }

                model[j-1][i-1] = median2d(filterpart,abs(filt_grid),abs(filt_grid));

        }
    }
```

But when I compiled it, it says:
`warning: ‘filterpart’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]`

I have initialized at the beginning to `NULL`, and each element to `0.0` in this code. Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: For future reference, please don't omit the memory allocation. This means the code is not easily reproducible (see [mcve]).

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is right, `filterpart` is uninitialized - as are private variables in OpenMP. But that's not the full story. You are handling (double) pointers here, OpenMP data-sharing only cares about the (outer) pointer, not the memory pointed to. For private data that is accessed through pointer types, you must manually take care of the private allocations for each thread.

In general, it is much easier to reason about variables in parallel regions if you declare them *as locally as possible*. Then you typically don't have to bother about manually specifying data-sharing (private/shared). In your example this looks like:

```
float **model_tmp, **model; // coming from the outside, shared. Check for race conditions

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int j=1;j<=NYG;j++){ 
    for (int i=1;i<=NXG;i++){ 
        float **filterpart;
        /* Omit the memory allocation, and initialize the element to 0.0 here */
        for (int ii=-hfs;ii<=hfs;ii++){
            for (int jj=-hfs;jj<=hfs;jj++){
                filterpart[ii+hfs+1][jj+hfs+1] = model_tmp[j+jj][i+ii];
            }
        }
        model[j-1][i-1] = median2d(filterpart,abs(filt_grid),abs(filt_grid));
    }
}
```

Now it is much easier to see that this code is correct. But there is a *potential* performance issue due to repeated memory allocation for `filterpart`. If that turns out to have an impact on your performance, you can transform the code as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    float **filterpart;
    /* Omit the memory allocation, but why would you initialize the elements? */

    #pragma omp for
    for (int j=1;j<=NYG;j++){ 
        for (int i=1;i<=NXG;i++){ 
            for (int ii=-hfs;ii<=hfs;ii++){
                for (int jj=-hfs;jj<=hfs;jj++){
                    filterpart[ii+hfs+1][jj+hfs+1] = model_tmp[j+jj][i+ii];
                }
            }
            model[j-1][i-1] = median2d(filterpart,abs(filt_grid),abs(filt_grid));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In the [OpenMP 3.1](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP3.1.pdf)  documentation (but it is probably correct for later versions) it isn't specified that the `private` clause will initialize a variable with earlier assigned value. What you are looking for is the`firstprivate` clause.

Comment: You are right about the error, but `firstprivate(filterpart)` is **not** the solution here. This would just copy the (outer) pointer and thus a huge race condition. You need to explicitly allocate memory for each thread.

Comment: BTW the standard actually *clearly specifies* how `private` variables are (not) initialized: "The new list item is initialized, or has an undefined initial value, as if it had been locally declared without an initializer."